# C# .Net Windows Service with Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, windows

I'm a fresh novice on C# dev, and I need your knowledge for this case.
Let me explain, I have to make running :

- A windows service who watching a directory to do some job on files putted inside it
- A windows application, that expose configuration for this service, and a system tray icon to control this service

So i have these two projects done in the same solution, and I need now to make them work together. What is the way ? 
I tried to add reference to the service in application, but it seems to not be the way and it's not working.

Comment: You have two different processes that need to talk, so search for "Inter-Process Communication" or IPC.

Comment: Ok so the plan is, correct me if wrong, create a Duplex WCF Service, hosted in the Windows Service as TCP, to let the Windows App ask for example a configuration value to Windows Service trough WCF Service, and WCF Service answer it back to Windows App ?

Comment: That's the gist of it, yeah. It's one of the many possibilities, all documented under ".NET IPC". You don't need a duplex connection though, a simple basicHttp, wsHttp or netTcp will suffice.